# Displaying the Meta Description

Tags: templating, meta

I am new to Craft.

Do I need to change any files to display the Description that I have set up for http://viviendasdeprimera.com/eventos/proyectos-de-casas-en-arraijan ?

Many thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 2):

Mike: yes you do. It sounds like you had your site built by another developer?

Unlike other CMS, everything that displays on your website in Craft is custom built. The gist is you setup a bunch of [fields](https://craftcms.com/docs/fields) on the backend (Craft's "control panel")—which is probably what you did. Think of the control panel as simply an interface to database.

However, those fields won't display anything on the front-end. What is output is controlled by [templates](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating-overview). If you're used to something like WordPress, Craft basically only has one "theme" and it's not accessible in the control panel.

In short, you basically need to tell Craft where to spit it out.  Depending on how your site was built, it's probably in a `_layout.html` file inside the `craft/app/templates` folder.

If your field's name is Meta Description, you could add it to the template in the appropriate place  somewhere like:

```
{% if entry is defined and entry.metaDescription is defined %}
  <meta name="description" content="{{ entry.metaDescription }}">
{% endif %}
```

In the control panel, the field would need to added to any section you want to use the Meta Description. If you've added that field to a section, the field will be output.

If you need more help with this, check out the [Craft documentation](https://craftcms.com/docs/introduction), [Mijingo](https://mijingo.com/craft)'s  lessons on Craft, or hire a [Craft professional](https://straightupcraft.com/professionals) to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Craft will not automatically create *anything* on the frontend for you. You could use something like the [SEOmatic](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft3-seomatic) plugin, though.

Comment: I tried to use the SEOmatic plugin but we could not get it to work and could not get a response from the developer